# Faust error: Cannot modify table key from outside of stream iteration

Tags: python, faust

I've implemented a Kafka topic that tries to buffer multiple events for efficiency but when I try and modify a Faust table I get the error message `Cannot modify table key from outside of stream iteration`

```
class BroadcastCounts(faust.Record):
    delivers: int
    bounces: int
    opens: int
    clicks: int
    unsubscribes: int

broadcast_counts = app.Table('broadcast_counts', value_type=BroadcastCounts)

@app.agent(broadcast_event_topic)
async def broadcast_event(stream):
    async for events in stream.take(1000, within=10):
        broadcast_counts['f7fb7078-d442-4219-8494-bfa5ab532230'] = BroadcastCounts(
            delivers=0,
            bounces=0,
            opens=0,
            clicks=0,
            unsubscribes=0,
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

After some testing it seems that doing a `take(...)` is not part of a stream so you can't access tables.